# OVERLOADING OPERATORS = error

Tags: c++

I am trying to use overloading concept to equate 3 objects `c1`, `c2`, `c3`.
But it is giving me an error

```
error: no match for 'operator=' in 'c3 = c2. circle::operator=(((circle&)(& c1)))'
```

What's the reason behind it how do I rectify it??

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class circle
{
  private:
    int radius;
    float x,y;
  public:
    circle()
    {}
    circle(int rr,float xx,float yy)
    {
      radius=rr;
      x=xx;
      y=yy;
    }
    circle& operator=(const circle& c)
    {
     cout<<endl<<"assignment operator invoked";  
     radius=c.radius;
     x=c.x;
     y=c.y;
     return *this;
     }
    void showdata()
    {
      cout<<endl<<"\n radius="<<radius;
      cout<<endl<<"x coordinate="<<x;
      cout<<endl<<"y coordinate="<<y<<endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
  circle c1 (10,2.5,2.5);
  circle c2,c3;
  c3=c2=c1;
  c1.showdata();
  c2.showdata();
  c3.showdata();
  return 0;
}
```

so this overloaded operator will be called two times..
First for c2=c1
and then for c3=c2 but how will compiler compare it with overloaded operator definition??

Answer (score 6):

In order to chain `operator=` calls, you must make sure that it returns a reference

```
circle& operator=(const circle& c)
{
   cout<<endl<<"assignment operator invoked";  
   radius=c.radius;
   x=c.x;
   y=c.y;
   return *this;
}
```

`c1=c2=c3` is parsed as `c1 = (c2 = c3)`. If `operator =` doesn't return a reference, `c2 = c3` is an rvalue, and it cannot bind to the reference argument of `c1.operator =` (In case if the argument is a reference to const, it can bind to rvalues, but that doesn't mean you shouldn't return a reference).

Also note that it makes sense to take the parameter by const reference, because you don't want to change the argument that you assign.

Also remember [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29), that is, if you really need to do any of the following:

- overload `operator =`
- explicitly provide a copy constructor
- explicitly provide a destructor

then you probably want to do the other two too. In your particular case, you don't seem to need to overload `operator =` at all.

Comment: I'd add a mention of taking a `circle const&` too.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Your snide remarks don't help anyone. And if you notice, I'm talking about the class he passes in.

Comment: @nathanwhite: Access checking is done on class level, not object level. And my remark wasn't meant to be snide.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Normally, constructive comments aren't followed by "duh". That is fine, and as it turns out, I am in the wrong anyway. I must admit (and this makes me sound like an incompetent programmer) that I didn't know that was possible.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan dt means above code wont work wo making correction that u specified..??

Comment: @amadeus: It might work, but it makes absolutely no sense. Why would you want to return a new object, identical to `*this` if you already have `*this`? The idiomatic way of implementing `opertator=` is to `return *this`

Comment: @amadeus: Then I'd recommend to study with a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). I personally recommend [Lippman's C++ Primer](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0201721481/?tag=stackoverfl08-20).

Comment: Don't feel too bad, @ArmenTsirunyan; I was in a discussion a month or so ago with very experienced programmers, and the fact that any object can access the guts of all other objects of that same class surprised a couple of them.  It's something they just never thought about.  But without that feature, you couldn't implement copying constructors.  Or just about anything interesting (`operator+` that adds private data from both objects, for instance).

Comment: @MaxLybbert: You probably meant to tag nathanwhite, not me :)

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan :thnx..i l refer to it..in meantime can u tell me that if this overloaded operator will be called two times.. First for c2=c1 and then for c3=c2 but how will compiler c2=c1 compare it with overloaded operator definition??Out of c2 and ca in c2=c1 call whose private fields are accessed and to which object value is returned..??

Comment: Sorry, Armen, you are right, I should have tagged @nathanwhite.

Comment: @MaxLybbert I appreciate that, and it does make me feel better haha! I must admit, I haven't worked with C++ in quite a while, so I'm not suprised that one caught me out. Thank you.